# Area of a Parallelogram spanning 2 vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

So doing a question on the area of a parallelogram spanned by 2 vectors, 
a=(3,-3,1) and b=(-12,12,-4)
and got a result of the cross product of a and b, which was (0,0,0) and tried to find the magnitude of the point. However it turned up to be 0 anyway (as I thought it would), so how can it be 0?

Comment: Because $b=-4a$

Comment: So you have a straight line, which spans no area

Comment: Ohhhhh, thank you for that. Extremely Helpful :D

Answer (score 1):

When two vectors are in the same direction, they do not form a parallelogram to have an area.

That is why your answer is correctly 0.

The vectors in this case are called co-linear that means they are on the same line so there is no area formed by them.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and understanding.

Comment: How do I find this, been trying to look in text book but cannot find it.

Comment: The cross product of a vector with itself is 0. Therefore  $V\times (\lambda V) = \lambda (V\times V)=0$